# Присвоение класса элементу html из объявленного набора

Tags: javascript, php, html

Прошу подсказать как можно реализовать…

объявить набор определенных классов (class1; class2; … classn)
Дальше есть конструкция html, ну например список ul>li, где li динамически создается. Как прописать чтобы каждому последующему li (если он создается) присваивался следующий из набора класс, или рандомный класс из того же набора.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так. По клику создается list item, вставляется в  и с каждым кликом присваивается class (class n+1)

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let i = 1;
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.append(li);
  li.classList.add(`class${i}`)
  i++;

});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик. Но можно без клика на кнопку? Просто если на странице появился очередной li ему присваивается класс. Для понимания, сайт реализован на CMS и элементы списка будут создаваться автоматом в зависимости от количества изображений в определенной папке.